# Error Response No Matter Payload Parameters When Scraping ASPX URL

Tags: python, .net, http, web-scraping

I have been attempting to scrape the results when pressing search at [this URL](https://www.pafoodsafety.pa.gov/Web/Inspection/PublicInspectionSearch.aspx). I have written the code below and keep getting back HTML in my response saying there was an error and a redirect:

```
<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="/Web/ErrorPage.aspx?aspxerrorpath=/Web/Inspection/PublicInspectionSearch.aspx">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
```

```
import datetime
import httpx
from selectolax.parser import HTMLParser


def generateCountyOptionsDict(response):
    html = HTMLParser(response.text)
    county_options = html.css(
        "select#MainContent_wucStateCountiesFS_ddlCounty option")
    county_options_dict = {}
    for option in county_options:
        county_options_dict[option.attributes["value"]] = option.text()
    return county_options_dict


def getViewStateAndGenerator(response):
    html = HTMLParser(response.text)
    view_state = html.css("input#__VIEWSTATE")[0].attributes["value"]
    view_state_generator = html.css("input#__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR")[
        0].attributes["value"]
    return [view_state, view_state_generator]


def getEventValidation(response):
    html = HTMLParser(response.text)
    event_validation = html.css("input#__EVENTVALIDATION")[
        0].attributes["value"]
    return event_validation


def createFormData(view_state, view_state_generator, event_validation):
    todays_date = datetime.date.today().strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
    yesterdays_date = (datetime.date.today() -
                       datetime.timedelta(days=1)).strftime("%m/%d/%Y")

    formdata = {
        "__EVENTTARGET": "ctl00$MainContent$btnSearch",
        "__EVENTARGUMENT": "false",
        "__LASTFOCUS": "",
        "__VIEWSTATE": view_state,
        "__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR": view_state_generator,
        "__SCROLLPOSITIONX": "0",
        "__SCROLLPOSITIONY": "0",
        "__EVENTVALIDATION": event_validation,
        "ctl00$MainContent$hfUseRadius": "true",
        "ctl00$MainContent$hfLatitude": "",
        "ctl00$MainContent$hfLongitude": "",
        "ctl00$MainContent$hfRadiusMiles": "",
        "ctl00$MainContent$txtEstablistmentName": "",
        "ctl00$MainContent$chkInCompliance": "on",
        "ctl00$MainContent$ddlJurisdiction": "",
        "ctl00$MainContent$txtStreetAddress": "",
        "ctl00$MainContent$txtCity": "",
        "ctl00$MainContent$wucStateCountiesFS$ddlState": "1",
        "ctl00$MainContent$wucStateCountiesFS$ddlCountyGroup": "",
        "ctl00$MainContent$wucStateCountiesFS$ddlCounty": "15",
        "ctl00$MainContent$wucStateCountiesFS$lseState_ClientState": "",
        "ctl00$MainContent$wucStateCountiesFS$lseCountyGroup_ClientState": "",
        "ctl00$MainContent$wucStateCountiesFS$lseCounty_ClientState": "",
        "ctl00$MainContent$txtZip": "",
        "ctl00$MainContent$dteInspectionBeginDate$txtDate": "10/10/2023",
        "ctl00$MainContent$dteInspectionEndDate$txtDate": "10/30/2023",
        "ctl00$MainContent$btnSearch": "Search",
        "ctl00$MainContent$ddlRadiusMiles": "1",
        "ctl00$MainContent$hfViolationInspectionKey": "",
        "ctl00$MainContent$hfRebindGridOnPostBack": "false",
        "ctl00$MainContent$hfInspectionSequenceKeysToExpand": ""
    }

    return formdata


def prettyPrintFormdata(formdata):
    for key, value in formdata.items():
        print(f"{key}: {value}")


def sendPostRequest(formdata):
    client = httpx.Client(verify=False)
    response = client.post(
        "https://www.pafoodsafety.pa.gov/Web/Inspection/PublicInspectionSearch.aspx",
        data=formdata
    )
    print(response.text)


def main():
    # Disable SSL verification because the site is using an invalid certificate
    client = httpx.Client(verify=False)
    # Get the page with the form
    response = client.get(
        "https://www.pafoodsafety.pa.gov/Web/Inspection/PublicInspectionSearch.aspx")
    # Get the county options. Each county has an id that is used in the form data
    county_options_dict = generateCountyOptionsDict(response)
    i = 0
    for county in county_options_dict:
        if i > 0:
            break
        view_state = getViewStateAndGenerator(response)[0]
        view_state_generator = getViewStateAndGenerator(response)[1]
        event_validation = getEventValidation(response)
        formdata = createFormData(
            view_state, view_state_generator, event_validation)
        sendPostRequest(formdata)
        i += 1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I tried the code above and keep getting the redirect error. I also set up Postman and sent a POST request without a payload. This got me the HTML to the selection page without displaying any results as expected. I thought there was a problem with the __EVENTTARGET value, but it is the same value as the ID of the search button.

Comment: I can't even see that web page from where I am, I just get a 500 error code. In any case, have you checked that the `formdata` all looks correct before sending it off? You say you've used Postman to send a request with no payload, but have you tried to use it to send a request *with* a payload?